# plotting a 3D+colour scatter with gnuplot (on torch7)

Tags: gnuplot, torch

I'm working with torch7, and I created a PCA function, which gives me an Nx3 tensor which I wish to plot (3D scatter).

I stored it in a file (`file.dat`).
now I want to plot it, I wrote the following lines

> NOTE: those lines are in `torch7`(lua), but you don't really need to know the language, because the command `gnuplot.raw("<command>")` uses the regular `gnuplot` commands.
>
> NOTE 2: I followed helpers on this forum to create this part, I probably read a relevant thread you might want to link here. If you do, please explain what's the difference between the linked explanation an what I did

```
gnuplot.raw("rgb(r,g,b) = 65536*r + 256*g + b")
gnuplot.raw("blue = rgb(0,0,200)")
gnuplot.raw("red = rgb(200,0,0)")
gnuplot.raw("layer = 1")
gnuplot.raw("splot './file.dat' using 1:2:3:(($4-layer)<0.1 ? red : blue) with points pt 7 linecolor rgb variable notitle")
```

cols 1 through 3 in `file.dat` are the x,y,z coordinates, col 4 is either 1 or 2 (determines colour).

> LAST NOTE: my script doesn't print an error of any kind, it just doesn't plot the desired 3D scatter.

Thanks ahead